# Finding time difference that meets a conditional statement

Tags: r, lubridate

I had an R question concerning data wrangling.  A sample data set I will include is downloadable online:

```
x<- read.csv("http://mgimond.github.io/ES218/Data/CO2.csv")
```

The datatable is shown in the attached image.

Example data table

[image]

I want to create a new column, let's say "time_since". This column would look at the "Average" column and calculate the time (in this case months) since "Average" is less than 300. So in this screenshot all are >300, so the value would be "0", but the month that eventually has a value less than 300 would then be "1" (representing 1 month since it has been one month under 300). If the following months are still under 300, this would increase according to the months that go by, but as soon as it become >300 again it will reset.

Basically it would be a function that would calculate the difference in time since a conditional statement is met, then restarts when the conditional is broken across dates.

I apologize if I worded it a bit confusing but hopefully the message comes across.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try :

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(as.integer(Average > 300))) %>%
  mutate(time_since  = row_number())  %>%
  ungroup -> result
```

Just to show you one excerpt of output where `time_since > 1`.

```
result %>% filter(grp == 61)

#   Year Month Average Interpolated Trend Daily_mean   grp time_since
#  <int> <int>   <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>      <int> <int>      <int>
#1  1964     1    320.         320.  320.         -1    61          1
#2  1964     2   -100.         320.  320.         -1    61          2
#3  1964     3   -100.         321.  320.         -1    61          3
#4  1964     4   -100.         322.  319.         -1    61          4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach. For this example, `time_since` is displaying the cumulative total of rows when the `Average` variable is greater than `315`.

```r
x<- read.csv("http://mgimond.github.io/ES218/Data/CO2.csv")


library(data.table)

setDT(x)

x[, ':='(time_since = seq(1:.N)), keyby = .(cumsum(Average < 315))][1:10, ]

#>     Year Month Average Interpolated  Trend Daily_mean time_since
#>  1: 1959     1  315.62       315.62 315.70         -1          1
#>  2: 1959     2  316.38       316.38 315.88         -1          2
#>  3: 1959     3  316.71       316.71 315.62         -1          3
#>  4: 1959     4  317.72       317.72 315.56         -1          4
#>  5: 1959     5  318.29       318.29 315.50         -1          5
#>  6: 1959     6  318.15       318.15 315.92         -1          6
#>  7: 1959     7  316.54       316.54 315.66         -1          7
#>  8: 1959     8  314.80       314.80 315.81         -1          1
#>  9: 1959     9  313.84       313.84 316.55         -1          1
#> 10: 1959    10  313.26       313.26 316.19         -1          1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>